# Wrapper to a function with a variable number of parameters

Tags: c++, wrapper, user-defined-functions, optional-parameters

I need to wrap a library function that can receive in input a variable number of parameters.
These parameters can be of different types.
In particular, I get an integer parameter that identifying the type, and a parameter that can be a number or a string.

I have tried using the following function, but the parameter list that comes to the internal function isn't right.

```
int function2(int rtype, ...);

int function1(int rtype, ...){
    va_list args; 
    va_start(args, rtype);

    int stato = function2(rtype, args);

    va_end(args);

    return stato;
}
```

Using this wrapper with the vprintf instead of function2, is working properly.

There is a cleaner way to pass a variable list of parameters to a function?

Comment: The function needs to have a `v` version as far as I know.

Comment: @chris is correct: if `function2` also takes `...` (varargs),  you cannot pass a `va_list` to it this way.  It's simply not possible.  But you may see the answers below for more C++-heavy solutions using templates...or you could use a C-style macro.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most generic way:

```
template<typename... A>
auto function1(A&&... a)
-> decltype(function2(std::forward<A>(a)...))
   { return function2(std::forward<A>(a)...); }
```

Comment: Very true. The function need not be a C-style variadic in the first place.